# How to use PLY module to realize two-line syntax analysis of "1+1 \n 2+2", output 2 and 4 respectively

Tags: yacc

Through PLY to achieve the "1+1 \n 2+2" result analysis, I think it is two irrelevant statements, but PLY has reduced them, how to make them irrelevant
    def p_statement_expr(p):
        '''statement : expression
        print p[1]

```
def p_expr_num(p):
    '''expression : NUMBER'''
    p[0] = p[1]

if "__main__" == __name__:
    parser = yacc.yacc(tabmodule="parser_main")
    import time
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(1):
        result = parser.parse("1+1 \n 2+2", debug=debug)
    # print time.time() - t
    # print result
```

- Through PLY to achieve the "1+1 \n 2+2" result analysis, I think it is two irrelevant statements, but PLY has reduced them, how to make them irrelevant
- PLY: PARSE DEBUG START State : 0 Stack : . LexToken(NUMBER,1,1,0) Action : Shift and goto state 3 State : 3 Stack : NUMBER . LexToken(ADD,'+',1,1) Action : Reduce rule [expression -> NUMBER] with [1] and goto state 5 Result :  (1) State : 5 Stack : expression . LexToken(ADD,'+',1,1) Action : Shift and goto state 9 State : 9 Stack : expression ADD . LexToken(NUMBER,1,1,2) Action : Shift and goto state 3 State : 3 Stack : expression ADD NUMBER . LexToken(NUMBER,2,2,6) ERROR: Error : expression ADD NUMBER . LexToken(NUMBER,2,2,6)
- When 2+2 is reported, how can I implement multi-line statement execution and automatically execute the following code after execution?

Comment: Through PLY to achieve the "1+1 \n 2+2" result analysis, I think it is two irrelevant statements, but PLY has reduced them, how to make them irrelevant

Comment: PLY: PARSE DEBUG START

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(NUMBER,1,1,0)
Action : Shift and goto state 3

State  : 3
Stack  : NUMBER . LexToken(ADD,'+',1,1)
Action : Reduce rule [expression -> NUMBER] with [1] and goto state 5
Result : <int @ 0x1d3fd68> (1)

State  : 5
Stack  : expression . LexToken(ADD,'+',1,1)
Action : Shift and goto state 9

State  : 9
Stack  : expression ADD . LexToken(NUMBER,1,1,2)
Action : Shift and goto state 3

State  : 3
Stack  : expression ADD NUMBER . LexToken(NUMBER,2,2,6)
ERROR: Error  : expression ADD NUMBER . LexToken(NUMBER,2,2,6)

Comment: When 2+2 is reported, how can I implement multi-line statement execution and automatically execute the following code after execution?

Comment: Hi! Comments here are intended for other people to request clarification or give advice on how to improve your question; there is an [edit] link under the question itself if you want to add details or change your wording.

Answer (score 0):

Ply has not done anything with the second expression.

Your grammar matches exactly one statement, assuming you are showing it all. Ply expects the input to terminate at that point, but it doesn't so Ply complains about an unexpected number.